# Converting a column string to numeric in an r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe that has a column of strings as follows:

```
    mydata <- c("-1.356670,35.355030",
            "-1.356670,35.355030", 
            "-1.356620,35.355890", 
            "-1.356930,35.358660", 
            "-1.357000,35.359060"
    )

    df <- data.frame(mydata)
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe containing two columns" `long` and `lat`, with each being a numeric type. What is the best way to do this? I've tried using `lapply`, but cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: The example you provided is not a data frame, but a vector.

Comment: so it is. I will update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base R you can do:

```
df$Long <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$mydata), ","), function(x) x[1]))
df$Lat <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$mydata), ","), function(x) x[2]))

               mydata     Long      Lat
1 -1.356670,35.355030 -1.35667 35.35503
2 -1.356670,35.355030 -1.35667 35.35503
3 -1.356620,35.355890 -1.35662 35.35589
4 -1.356930,35.358660 -1.35693 35.35866
5 -1.357000,35.359060 -1.35700 35.35906
```

Or with `tstrsplit()` from `data.table`:

```
df$Long <- as.numeric(tstrsplit(df$mydata, ",")[[1]])
df$Lat <- as.numeric(tstrsplit(df$mydata, ",")[[2]])
```

Also with `tstrsplit()` from `data.table` as proposed by @clmarquart:

```
setDT(df)[, c("lat", "long") := tstrsplit(mydata, ",", fixed = TRUE)]
```

Comment: You can combine them to a single call if you're interested: `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(df$mydata, strsplit, split=","))), byrow=T, nrow=2)`

Comment: Or if you do use `data.table`, if you make a `data.table` first ( `dt = data.table(df)` ) then you can do it this way as well: `dt[, c('lat','long') := tstrsplit(mydata, ",", fixed=T)][]`

Comment: @clmarquart thanks for your remarks. I like your `data.table` possibility, so I added it to my post.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in one line in base R:

```
read.table(text = as.character(df$mydata), sep = ",", col.names = c("long", "lat"))
```

giving:

```
     long      lat
1 -1.35667 35.35503
2 -1.35667 35.35503
3 -1.35662 35.35589
4 -1.35693 35.35866
5 -1.35700 35.35906
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- df %>%
  separate(mydata, into = c("Long", "Lat"), sep = ",", convert = TRUE)

# Print the data
dat
#       Long      Lat
# 1 -1.35667 35.35503
# 2 -1.35667 35.35503
# 3 -1.35662 35.35589
# 4 -1.35693 35.35866
# 5 -1.35700 35.35906
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit` with `do.call`, then we just need assign the columns name

```
newdf=do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(mydata,','))
names(newdf)=c('long','lat')
newdf
       long       lat
1 -1.356670 35.355030
2 -1.356670 35.355030
3 -1.356620 35.355890
4 -1.356930 35.358660
5 -1.357000 35.359060
```