# Separate and use values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

So, im trying to separate the values from this column of a datased that has Latitude and Longitude together.
[This is how the values are separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqFIS.png)

```
df <- data.frame(localidade = c(drugs_location))
df %>% separate(localidade, c("Lat", "Long"), sep = ",")
```

I used this code above to separate the values in Lat and Long but now i need to use those values to make a plot using the **Lat** as the x axis and **Long** as the y axis.

This is the `dput(head(df))` output as requested:

```
    structure(list(localidade = c("(42.30676881, -71.08431925)", 
"(42.30676881, -71.08431925)", "(42.33152148, -71.07085307)", 
"(42.31580934, -71.07618683)", "(42.31580934, -71.07618683)", 
"(42.31224532, -71.07317861)")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post R questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, can you upload your dataframe so that we can more effectively help? Try `dput(df)` and then copy and paste the entire output. If your dataframe is large then try `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Im pretty new to r so i hope the output is correct

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54617973/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr) 
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(localidade = str_replace_all(localidade, "\\(|\\)", "")) %>%
  separate(localidade, c("Lat", "Long"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(Lat = as.numeric(Lat), Long = as.numeric(Long))
```

You need to convert the values to numeric.
The first mutate deletes all the "(" or ")" from the string.
Then you seperate the string with the "," and convert to numeric.

Comment: You need a parenthesis at the end of the first `mutate`. E.g. `mutate(localidade = str_replace_all(localidade, "\\(|\\)", ""))`

Comment: Thank you! But now how can i use the values in **Lat** and **Long** to plot?